# Python Pandas Selecting rows with any columns that has NaN

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DF like this

```
      City    State Country
Name                   
A     NYC     NaN   NaN
B     Nan     NaN   USA
C     NYC     NY    NaN
D     601009  NaN   NaN
E     NYC     AZ    NaN
F     000001  NaN   NaN
```

I want to be able to select rows that have NaN city. So that it looks like this

```
      City    State Country
Name                   
B     NaN     NaN   USA
```

How do I do this?

Thanks

Comment: `df[df['City'].isnull()]` should work

Comment: What if I want to return all rows that contains ANY nan column?

Comment: Sorry are you really executing that snippet of code? it should return a boolean index into your df not a `bunch of True/False`

Comment: Yes u are right, it worked... But what if I want to get rows that contain ANY nan?

Comment: `df[df.isnull().any(axis=1)]`